# Javascript. How click on link in Javascript block?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript. I have a script that clicks on the ad unit on the site. But now I need to achieve the same in Javascript.I already have same script for Python+selenium, but now need on JS.

The object specified in the index.html javascript code

When the page loads the code is transformed into an ad unit, consisting of 3 images with links.
[image: image1]

But it is necessary to click to start to get a reference At least one of the three blocks.

In Google Chrome, the function "View code" gives the following:
[image: image2]

How to find and click on one of the three elements on the page with JS?

Find by xpath or ID or tagname?

Help me please! Thanks in advance!

Maybe this way helps m?...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var links = document.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'.xyz')]");
    window.location = links;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you aware that in order to get help with code, one must provide it? The image is not code (although it is effective as a supplement to said code if it were to be provided.) . I think it would help if you just post that part you have in second image, please refer to how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Do you need to attach event to all of these links? or just the first one

Comment: azs06 Just one, friend. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger a click on a element using Javascript, you can try the following:

```js
document.getElementById('element').onclick();
```

Here's the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tbjbbt5a/